# Python 3 re.findall closing file?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

1) I open a file

2) run `re.findall()` returns a list as expected

3) then I run `re.findall()` again looking for something else but it returns empty list.

But if I open the file again between 2 and 3, the second `re.findall()` works perfectly.

I can't figure out what is going on, is `re` closing the file? or is something else happening?

Thanks for any help you may have in advance!

Here's my code

```
def extract_names(filenames):
  for f in filenames: #grabs one file at a time
    file = open(f, 'r') #opens file

    #find year <h3 align="center">Popularity in 1992</h3>
    year = re.search(r'Popularity\sin\s\d{4}', file.read()) 
    print(year)

    file = open(f, 'r') #reopen file

    #find <tr align="right"><td>1</td><td>Michael</td><td>Ashley</td>
    rank_names = re.search(r'<td>\d*</td><td>\w*</td><td>\w*</td>', file.read())
    print(rank_names)
```

Comment: First use an Html parser. About your problem, you can't use `file.read()` two times for the same filehandler (since once it has been read a first time, there's nothing more to read the second time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.read()` consumes the whole file and advances the file pointer to the end of the file. A subsequent call to `file.read()` just returns the empty string (because the file is already consumed). You could call `file.seek(0)` to return the file pointer to the beginning of the file, but it's silly to read the file twice when you can just read once and store the contents to avoid extra system calls.

If you want to search the file data more than once, store the result of `file.read()` and use it instead of `file.read()` in your calls, e.g.:

```
filedata = file.read()  # Cache once

year = re.search(r'Popularity\sin\s\d{4}', filedata)  # Search in cache
print(year)

#find <tr align="right"><td>1</td><td>Michael</td><td>Ashley</td>
rank_names = re.search(r'<td>\d*</td><td>\w*</td><td>\w*</td>', filedata)  # Search cache again
print(rank_names)
```

Side-note: [Use a real HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/364696)

Answer (score 1):

The file pointer has been moved to the end of the file after `file.read()` so you cannot use `file.read()` again to get the whole content of this file.

You may store the content of the file for following operations:

```
content = file.read()
year = re.search(r'Popularity\sin\s\d{4}', content)
rank_names = re.search(r'<td>\d*</td><td>\w*</td><td>\w*</td>', content)
file.close()
```

And `with` keyword is advised to use for file operations which can close the file handler automatically:

```
for f in filenames:
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
         content = file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you name the `str` that you get out of `read()`.

```
with open("filename", "rt") as f:
    content = f.read()
```

Now you can refer to the object as `content` however many times you wish. The more `open()` operations the more overhead. And as `open()` returns an **iterator**, `read([chunk])` **consumes** it `chunk` by `chunk`, until *there is nothing left.* That's why you got an empty container the second time.